# What does "x <= y or not" mean?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

[image]
[image]

What is the significance of the phrase "for any two objects $x,y \in X$, the statement $x \leq_X y$ is either a true statement or a false statement."?

By the law of the excluded middle, I think that it's always the case that $x \leq_X y$ is either true or not true. Does that mean a "partially ordered set" is not more restrictive than simply a "set"?

Comment: A set by itself does not need to even have a relation in the first place, much less a partial order.  A partially ordered set specifically needs to *have* a partial order.  A partially ordered set is the combination of *both* a set *and* a partial order.  In that sense, a partially ordered set is more restrictive than a set.

Comment: There is a word *thus* at the beginning of that sentence. $\leq_X$ being a relation implies $x \leq_X y$ is either true or false.

Comment: It is trying to avoid saying "either $x \le_X^{\,} y$ or $y \lt_X^{\,} x$", which is a property of totally ordered sets but not necessarily partially ordered sets

Comment: The following quoted statement about a 'mere' set $X$ is false:  "for any set $X$, and any $x, y \in X$, either the statement $x \le_X y$ is true or it is false."  It is false for a silly reason, which is that it refers to an ordering $\le_X$, which a 'mere' set doesn't have.  Once you equip the set $X$ with the ordering $\le_X$, then, as you say, it is immediately the case that "for any $x, y \in X$, either the statement $x \le_X y$ is true or it is false".  As @stochastic points out, this is what 'thus' means in the quoted statement.

Comment: (The book may just be trying to emphasise that the relation is written infix; that is, that one doesn't use the awful but technically correct notation "$(x, y) \in {\le_X}$", but rather changes it to "$x \le_X y$".  It's similar to how we denote the value of the function ${+} : \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ at $(2, 3)$ not by ${+}(2, 3)$, but by $2 + 3$; we just don't mention this convention because it is so ingrained.)

Comment: Here's a slight analogy:  "We take a set of animals all of which consume oxygen.  Then we apply a machine the will measure oxygen remaining in the room..." and a student asks, "what is the significance of specifying all the animals consume oxygen? *Every* animal consumes oxygen!"  Well.. yeah bt we are doing something about that and we need a gentle reminder.  $a \le_x b$ doesn't have any inherent *meaning* or significance.  But we *can* compare any two $a,b$ and get either $a \le_x b$ or .... we dont get $a \le_x b$.  That may be trivial... but it's still a *concept* to be expressed.

Comment: Consider X={Fred, Bob, Babar, A bag of wax} and $a \le_x b$ means  $b^2 - a^2$ is a positive integer.  Then for all $x,y\in X$ $x \le_x b$ is a false stratement.  Fine.  That's true and trivial   But I think the book is saying "$\le_x$ is a relation with which we will compare any two elements and we will be able to state cleary and unambiguously that either $a \le_x b$ or "not $a \le_x b$."  As an observation, that may be always true-- all statements are either true or false (either $2$ is a gamaphaloon or it isn't)-- but that we can compare any two items, is a significant aspect of an order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having more context I would have to guess. But it looks like instead of looking at relations as subsets of $X\times X$, the text  is looking as relations as predicates: so  $ x\leq y$ is established by means of a certain assertion.

The issue is that with that point of view it could be the case that the assertion is neither true or false, in the same sense that "this sentence is false" is neither true or false (i.e., Russell's Paradox).

So the text is saying that you have a relation when the  $x\leq y$ is actually a statement (that is, true or false) for all $x,y$.

Answer (score 2):

It just means that the $\leq_X$ binary operator *must* be a predicate *function* that is in fact *defined* for any pair of elements from $X^2$ (ie, it is *surjective* ). $~\leq_X : X{\times} X\twoheadrightarrow \{\bot,\top\}$

Which, yeah, should not really *need* to be stated, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. That parenthetical statement by itself effectively says nothing; I think the authors put it there to help the reader conceptually think about the nature of the structure involved. But it is not what makes it a partial order.

It is the three properties listed after that that makes it a partial order ... and which makes it more than simply a 'set'. Indeed, the fact that we are dealing with a binary relation already makes it more than just any 'set'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a word *thus* at the beginning of that sentence. That is, [$\leq_X$ being a relation on $X$] implies that [for all $x,y\in X$, $x \leq_X y$ is either true or false].